# Element set-payload is not allowed here

Tags: mule

I have a simple configuration file used in a functional test case that works fine when in Anypoint Studio but when using in intelliJ (my main IDE) set-payload is in red and the hover test displays

> "Element set-payload is not allowed here"

When running the test I get the following exception

> org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Line 17 in XML document
>   from URL
>   [file:/C:/dev/Messaging/Revenue-mule3-sms/target/test-classes/mule-conf2.xml]
>   is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   lineNumber: 17; columnNumber: 60; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid
>   content was found starting with element 'set-payload'

I have the following namespaces configured in the file

```
 xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
        xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
        xmlns:test="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/test"
        version="EE-3.2.2"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/test http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/test/current/mule-test.xsd">
```

and most of the main dependencies added. What could be the issue here?

EDIT

Xml file content

```
<flow name="simplejunittestFlow1" doc:name="simplejunittestFlow1">
        <inbound-endpoint address="vm://test" exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="Generic"/>
        <set-payload value="#['Pass']" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <flow-ref name="simplejunittestFlow2" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
    </flow>
    <sub-flow name="simplejunittestFlow2" doc:name="simplejunittestFlow2">
        <set-payload value="#['Pass']" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <set-payload  doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    </sub-flow>
```

Comment: Can you share the piece of config where set-payload is configured?

Comment: I've updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set-payload` transformer was not introduced until 3.3.0. I see you are using: version="EE-3.2.2"

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mule/mule-core/3.3.0/org/mule/transformer/simple/SetPayloadTransformer.java/

Comment: Ah! After hours of searching I did not realise this. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know of a way to mimic set-payload for 3.2?

Comment: Yes. expression-transformer: 
        <expression-transformer expression="#['new payload']"/>